# how to connect F# to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, f#

Hello 
I am a newbie using F# and MySQL. I have a project that needs to retrive data from mySQL database.So far, i installed wamp, mySQL, mySQL connector, php.
I don't know how to contribute F# and mySQL.
Can you please give me a piece of information about the steps .

Thanks,

Comment: the same way you would connect my sql to c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624607/automatic-generation-of-record-type-based-on-mysql-database-tables-for-use-in-fs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a MySQL connector for .NET, [this one, for example](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

```
let connectionStr = "Data Source=localhost; Port=3306; User ID=root; Password=q1w2e3;"
let connection : IDbConnection = upcast new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionStr)
```

See [System.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx) documentation for detailed information.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is it just enough to open a project and start to write these lines you mentioned before .Or should i add some references from the Solution Explorer,too ?

Comment: You'll need to add reference to the library that you will download.

Answer (score 0):

F# works with the normal .NET class libraries. So any .NET MySQL connector will work.

For example, this on here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/